# Overriding Default Table Width

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to manually set a UITableView's width?

I would like to set the table as a subview which takes up half of the width of the screen and the full height.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can set the table frame to whatever you want.

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(80, 0, 160, screenHeight);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that is cuts off the right hand side of the table instead of actually shrinking it.  I have tried limiting it to a frame, but I must see the scrollbar which is being cut off by the frame's limits.

Comment: Then perhaps this is because the code you've posted is in Objective-C instead of C#.  In my attempt, the frame that I sat the tableView in did not resize the table per se.  It merely cut off the side.

Comment: ok, another approach will be to use a custom cells, build the cell yourself, add a background view with frame=(80, 0, 160, cellHeight), add labels and images if you need. The only problem would be that the scroll bar will still stay at the right hand side of the screen (